# Why isn't my JS working (in wordpress)?

Tags: javascript

What I'm trying to do is have a number count-up on my page that increases at a steady increment/interval. I created stylized images to represent each number 0-9 in the count-up, so I also need to replace each number with its respective image. The first Function in the code represents that task, and the second script is the actual count-up. I'm using wordpress so I've added the JS file and enqueued it in the header.php file.

Here's where I had my problem: I was able to get the count-up to work, but the `counterimages(input)` function doesn't want to work for me. It might be an issue with how I am trying to "call" on the function on the WordPress page.

If anyone could help me out I would be very grateful!

```
function counterimages(input) {
var output = ""

for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var chr = input.substring(i, i + 1)
    if (chr == '£') {
        output += '<img border="0" src="img/pound.gif">';
    } else if (chr == '.') {
        output += '<img border="0" src="img/dot.gif">';
    } else {
        output += '<img border="0" src="http://eatiply3.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/'+(chr+1)+'.png">';
    }
return output;
}

var START_DATE = new Date("October 21, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // refresh interval in seconds
var INCREMENT = 769.2;  // increase per tick (1/0.0013 ~ 769)
var START_VALUE = 35000; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 $('#counter').html(count.toFixed(0));

 window.setInterval( function(){
    count += INCREMENT; 
    $('#counter').html(count.toFixed(0));
 }, msInterval);

});`
```

Comment: "Why isn't my code working?" questions are usually bad fit for StackOverflow. Not only they only help you and not anyone else, they rarely have much added value. Have you tried using `debugger;` statements and other debugging techniques such as placing `console.log` statements in strategic places in your code and checking what in fact happens?

Comment: This isnt a great question, but lookes like youre missing a close bracket just before `return output;` That function isnt getting closed (`counterimages`)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a bracket in the `counterimages` function

http://jsfiddle.net/Rhpjw/

```
function counterimages(input) {
    var output = ""

    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        var chr = input.substring(i, i + 1)
        if (chr == '£') {
            output += '<img border="0" src="img/pound.gif">';
        } else if (chr == '.') {
            output += '<img border="0" src="img/dot.gif">';
        } else {
            output += '<img border="0" src="http://eatiply3.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/' + (chr + 1) + '.png">';
        }
        return output;
    }
}

var START_DATE = new Date("October 21, 2012 22:30:00"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // refresh interval in seconds
var INCREMENT = 769.2; // increase per tick (1/0.0013 ~ 769)
var START_VALUE = 35000; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
    var now = new Date();
    count = parseInt((now - START_DATE) / msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
    $('#counter').html(count.toFixed(0));

    window.setInterval(function () {
        count += INCREMENT;
        $('#counter').html(count.toFixed(0));
    }, msInterval);
});
```